# float object has no attribute isna

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df where all columns are objects. Why can't I apply a function that checks whether 2 column have a NaN. I want to avoid `np.where` since I have has 6 other elif lines in the function.

```
df
    cola_              check1             colb           check2          
0   The start          hungry             banana          high         
1    world             NaN                apple           NaN         
2   yesterday          fruit              pear            high
```

```
def func(df):
     if (df['check1'].isna()) & (df['check2'].isna()):
          return df['colb']
```

```
df['final'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Expected Output

```
    cola_             check1              colb           check2     final
0   The start          hungry             banana         high        
1    world             NaN                apple           NaN        apple    
2   yesterday          fruit              pear            high       


'float' object has no attribute 'isna'
```

Comment: Why does your expected output include NaNs? Also `&` is a bitwise operator. You should be using `and` for logical comparisons like that. Also, the error pretty clearly states what's wrong: there is no `isna()` function defined for `float` objects.

Comment: I don't understand the error. Changing & to "and" didn't resolve the issue. How do I check if the column has a missing value?

Comment: I didn't say it would. See the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isna.html) on the `isna()` function.

Comment: @blorgon that’s not quite true here; the & is necessary for pandas to do elementwise logical operations. The ‘and’ would return a single Boolean. But there’s a bigger problem here. I’ll address it in my answer.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy the docs say for a scalar input it returns a scalar boolean. The way OP is trying to use the `isna()` function looks like they're testing on scalar values. Syntactically, the `and` operator seems more appropriate. If instead OP uses `isna()` on an array, then I'd say the `&` operator would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first correction: Don't use *df* as the parameter name in *func*,
because the passed object is a **row**. Use e.g. *row* instead.

The second correction is that some cells contain values of **string**
type, which has no *isna()* method. Use *pd.isna()* instead, as it works
on a source argument of **any** type.

So define your function e.g. as:

```
def func(row):
    if pd.isna(row.check1) & pd.isna(row.check2):
        return row.colb
    else:
        return '-'
```

I added another *return* for *else* variant, but I assume that you have
a couple of *elif ...* instructions there.

Comment: Thanks. How comes ```df.isna()``` will show True/False for columns - even for columns that are a string type? And is it best practice to have all missing values in every column of a df represented as a np.NaN  instead of " " or None?

Comment: Note that I wrote **pd.isna()** not *df.isna()*. Here *isna()* is a **Pandas** method, not a *DataFrame* method. And as far as "the best practice" is concenrned: Rather don't use *None* as *Pandas* uses much more often *np.nan* taken from underlying *Numpy*. Generally just *NaN* (*np.nan*) is used as the representation of missing data. Note also that if you use *read_csv* then missing values are read just as *NaN*.

Comment: Thanks. How do I know which columns are float objects? df.dtypes says all columns are objects. I’m trying to concatenate columns in the return statement. My worry is that if using np.NaN everywhere is best practice, pandas thinks everything is a float

Comment: If a column is of *object* type then each cell can contain arbitrary object (e.g. string or float). If you want to avoid *float* values (and *NaN* are just floats), consider using e.g. empty strings as a "missing" value and change your code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You are applying the `isna` method to a float object which, as the error states, doesn't have such a method:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.Series([1, np.nan]).apply(lambda x: x.isna())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/documents/assets/envs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 4212, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2403, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isna'
```

You could instead use `np.isnan` to test whether a float is `nan`, like so:

```py
>>> pd.Series([1, np.nan]).apply(lambda x: True if not np.isnan(x) else False)
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

So your function would look like this:

```py
def func(df):
    try:
        test = np.isnan(df['check1']) and np.isnan(df['check2'])
    except Exception as e:
        if 'not supported for the input types' in str(e):
            test = False
        else:
            raise
    return df['colb'] if test else df
```

You might consider using some other variable name for `func` besides `df` as `apply` applies functions row-wise, not necessarily on an entire dataframe.

Comment: What exactly is a "float object"?

Comment: A "float object" is simply something of type `float`, e.g. `1.1`, `2.5`, or `-1.9`. Pandas often represents numbers as floats.

Comment: but my column is full of strings

Comment: `np.nan` – the null value in NumPy and pandas – is a float. `type(np.nan)` --> `<class 'float'>`

Comment: You would get the same error if a `str` object were operated on first, since `str` objects also don't have an `isna` method.

Comment: I'm getting error ```ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types...```

Answer (score 0):

You’re confusing `Series` and `DataFrame`. When you use `df.apply`, you apply the function to each row separately; these are each a `Series`. (That means that in your function, it's misleading to call the variable `df`.) There's a cleaner way to write what you want, by avoiding the behind-the-scenes looping that `apply` does.

```
condition: pd.Series = df["check1"].isna() & df["check2"].isna()  # I added a type annotation; not necessary.
# Copy the column, then correct it.
df["Final"] = df["colb"]
df["Final"][condition] = None  # Your function returned None when the condition was false.
```

Note that I've gotten rid of `func` entirely.